# I can not set xfa data with itext

Tags: c#, itext, xfa

I have a pdf which is produced by GMC Printnet Designer 7.0. And i have an xml file with xfa template. I want to merge them and embed data in pdf. (I don't want to attach xml!)

I can read the xml data, i can read the input pdf, i can start a memory stream and produce the output data with it. But when i check the pdf which i produce with itext, i see no xfa form.

here is my c# code and xml file:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("in.pdf");
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms);
    XfaForm xfa = new XfaForm(reader);
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("in.xml");
    xfa.DomDocument = doc;
    xfa.Changed = true;
    XfaForm.SetXfa(xfa, stamper.Reader, stamper.Writer);
    xfa.XfaPresent = true;
    stamper.Close();
    File.WriteAllBytes("out.pdf", ms.ToArray());
```

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xfa:data xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/">
<Invoice>
<InvoiceNr>1010101010101010</InvoiceNr>
<DateIssuance>2014-07-22</DateIssuance>
<PaymentDueDate>2014-09-09</PaymentDueDate>
<AmountToBePaid>53,25</AmountToBePaid>
</Invoice>
</xfa:data>
```

Comment: ps: there is someone who had the same problem actually. but i need more info and i can not comment on the subject because of reputation. i added my question but, it has been deleted, and some clever(!) guys advided to me to "add a comment" to that question

Comment: Your XML file looks wrong. Remove the first and the last line, so that the XML starts with <Invoice> and ends with </Invoice>.

Comment: i tried it but nothing has changed.

Comment: Maybe the XML doesn't comply with the schema stored in the XFA form. It is very hard to guess. There are also some strange things in your code, for instance: `xfa.XfaPresent = true` doesn't make sense. That's a ReadOnly property in Java (and it should be ReadOnly in C# too).

Comment: xfa.xfapresent thing does not exist in my code. i was trying a code which i saw in internet, and then i forget to delete line. i am going to try "fillxfaform" solution. last night i had an error with that, but i don't remember that. maybe i had some mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I explained in the comments, I don't understand your code (nor do I know where you've found it). The official documentation says you should fill the form like this:

```
using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms)) {
    AcroFields form = stamper.AcroFields;
    XfaForm xfa = form.Xfa;
    xfa.FillXfaForm(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml)));
}
```

See the [XfaMovies](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=165) example. For the C# version, see http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C08

**Update:**

in the comments, you have added links to the PDF and to an XML file. Both files are problematic:

1. The PDF file isn't a form. At the most, you could use it as a background PDF in an XFAF form. This can only be done manually and requires a designer such as Adobe LiveCycle Designer.
2. The XML file **is not an XFA stream**! As documented in my book (which the OP defines as NOT HELPING), an XFA stream consists of different parts such as a `config` part, a `localeSet` part, an `xmp` part, but more importantly a `template` part and a `datasets` part that consists of a `data` and a `datadescription` part. The XML that is shared only contains the `data` part, there is no `datadescription` and there is no `template`. Hence this XML can *never* be integrated into a PDF file with an XFA form as result: there is just too much information missing.

Now that I've seen the files you were talking about in your question, it is clear that you're asking something that is impossible. You need to take the `xsd` of your XML, import it into a tool such as Adobe LiveCycle Designer, then *manually* define the location of the fields in your template (that information is missing in your XML) and define the PDF as the background for your form.

There is no way to automate this process, given the files you have shared.

Comment: Thank you Bruno, but get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error. I think it means "i have no form field in original pdf". Isn't it possible create static xfa form in pdf files with no form data?

Comment: I assumed that you had a dynamic XFA form. If you have a static XFA form, you need to use the other approach described in chapter 8 of my book. In any case: your question isn't clear as long as you don't tell us anything about the nature of your form. Maybe you should share that form.

Comment: XFA stands for the XML *Forms* Architecture. Now you tell me that there is no form. I am all confused. I will no longer participate to this absurd conversation.

Comment: My book helps in case of genuine problems. You are asking something that doesn't make sense. It seems that you have an ordinary PDF that you want to turn into a PDF that is based on the XML Forms Architecture. You claim that you have an XFA stream, but you only have part of a dataset. You should blame the one who gave you this absurd assignment, not the messenger who tells you you're trying to do something that is impossible.

Comment: I repeatedly informed you that your question was unclear. The conversation became absurd when it came clear that you want to fill out a form that is not a form. You yourself admitted *"I know it is stupid"*, hence you agree about the absurdity of the conversation. I do not understand why you feel offended. There is no reason to.

Comment: If anyone should feel offended, it should be me. Fortunately, there are thousands of people who appreciate my work for every person who hates what I do ;-)